# async using node.js HapiJS and couchbase sdk returning empty results

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, couchbase, hapi

So I have the following code which is in a Hapi.JS handler, and is attempting to call couchbase sdk.

```
handler: async (request, h) => {
                var SpatialQuery = Couchbase.SpatialQuery;
                var sw = JSON.parse(request.payload.sw);
                var ne = JSON.parse(request.payload.ne);

                var query = SpatialQuery.from('dev_spatialtest', 'spacetest').limit(100);
                return await myBucketQuery(query);
            }
```

It calls this function

```
async function myBucketQuery(query){
    return bucket.query(query, async function(err, results){
                console.log("in results = " + JSON.stringify(results));
                return results;
            });
};
```

the console.log in myBucketQuery returns the correct result, but does it after the hapi has already returned (or maybe not???)  The result in postman comeback as

```
{
    "_events": {},
    "_eventsCount": 2
}
```

can anyone give me a clue what I am doing wrong here??

**Fixed using the following**

```
async function myBucketQuery(query){
    return new Promise(resolve => { 
        var resolution = bucket.query(query, async function(err,results){
            console.log("in results = " + JSON.stringify(results));
            resolve(results);
        });
        return resolution;
    });
};
```

Comment: Hi Lee, welcome to SO! When you say "the console.log in myBucketQuery returns the correct result", what does that mean? Could you show what the output of your console.log is?

Comment: Matthew - in the myBucketQuery function there is a console.log... this returns the data from the query, but the return to the client (postman) request returns the _events JSON.  the results I want are what is coming from the console.log.. which is a result of the query.

Comment: Matthew - thanks for your input, I think I figured it out.  Just in case anyone comes to the same issues.  I have included my fix in the edit to original question

Comment: Here on SO, you can answer your own questions! You should post that as an answer instead of adding it to the question.